# why'_io.BufferedRandom' object has no attribute 'resize'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory, attributeerror

I'm using PIL, and I've got this error message:

```py
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedRandom' object has no attribute 'resize'
```

My code:

```py
def phash(img):
    img = img.resize((8, 8), Image.ANTIALIAS).convert('L')
    avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, img.getdata()) / 64.
    return reduce(
        lambda x, y, z: x | (z << y),
        enumerate(map(lambda i: 0 if i < avg else 1, img.getdata())),
        0
    )
```

Comment: Your `img` is apparently the file object itself, rather than an image read from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you shared only includes the definition of the function, and I think that the problem is in your main code.
The error message that you got shows you that the object that you are trying to resize doesn't have this functionality, and because of that **I think that you have accidentally loaded the image with the command `open('path/to/image.png')`, when you need to load it as an 'Image' object with the command `Image.open('path/to/image.png')`.**

Try writing something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
from functools import reduce


def phash(img):
    pass # your function here

path = 'path/to/image.png'
image = Image.open(path)
phash = phash(image)
```